# Redirect After Click Anywhere

Tags: redirect, click

How do I redirect a user to another webpage after he clicks anywhere on the page in PHP/HTML or Java? How to redirect a user after,for example, 2 clicks?

Comment: You might consider making this question a little longer: do you want to do this client side or server side?  Why are you looking to do this?  What have you tried so far?  Please edit and give us a few details.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might be suitable:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<style>
    BODY.enterPage{
    cursor:hand;
}
</style>
<script>
   function goto(){
       location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
   }
</script>
</head>
<body class="enterPage"  onclick="goto();">
    <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Enter</a>
</body>
</html>
```

From [this forum](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=381087)

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Is there any way to redirect user after like 2 clicks?

Comment: Or in more elegant way you can do **$('body').on('click', function() { window.location.href = 'http://yoururl.domain/'};**

Comment: You are missing the ending ) and you would have to include jquery on the page.  $('body').on('click', function() { window.location.href = 'yoururl.domain/';});